# Check if pendrive is persistent?

Tags: persistence

I have a bunch of pendrives with live Linux ISOs loaded onto them and I would like to check one if it is persistent. Rebooting is not an option right now (system rescue).

Is there a simple command or utility to check if the current pendrive Linux installation is persistent on the pendrive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the drive, look for a file with the name `casper-rw` or a partition with the label `casper-rw`. That is where persistence is stored for persistent live Ubuntu drives.